# SQL Database + LOAD + CLOB files = error SQL3229W

Tags: db2, blob, ibm-cloud, clob, sqldb

I'm having trouble making loads of tables that have CLOBS and BLOBS columns in a 'SQL Database' database in Bluemix.

The error returned is:

```
SQL3229W  The field value in row "617" and column "3" is invalid. The row was 
rejected. Reason code: "1".

SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row "617" of 
the input file.
```

The same procedures performed in a local environment functioned normally.

under the command you use to load:

```
load client from /home/db2inst1/ODONTO/tmp/ODONTO.ANAMNESE.IXF OF IXF LOBS FROM /home/db2inst1/ODONTO/tmp MODIFIED BY IDENTITYOVERRIDE replace into USER12135.TESTE NONRECOVERABLE
```

Comment: Do the databases have the same `LOCALE` (encoding)?

Comment: I believe LOB files must reside on the database server, not on the client, even when you specify `LOAD CLIENT`.

Comment: this configurations have the same LOCALE...

Comment: I realized testing on remote server, but in other environment and work correctly... I believe to be some particularity of bluemix environments...

Comment: sorry, the files of LOBs must be in the local server! :(

Answer (score 0):

The only manner currently you can upload lob files to a SQLDB or dashDB is to load the data and lobs from the cloud. The option is to get data from a Swift object storage in Softlayer or a Amazon S3 storage. You should have an account on one of those services.

After that, you can use the following syntax:

`db2 "call sysproc.admin_cmd('load from Softlayer::softlayer_end_point::softlayer_username::softlayer_api_key::softlayer_container_name::mylobs/blob.del of del LOBS FROM Softlayer::softlayer_end_point::softlayer_username::softlayer_api_key::softlayer_container_name::mylobs/ messages on server insert into LOBLOAD')"`

Where:
mylobs/ is the directory inside the Softlayer swift object storage container, defined in 
LOBLOAD is the table name to be loaded in

Example:

`db2 "call sysproc.admin_cmd('load from Softlayer::https://lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0::SLOS424907-2:SL523907::0ac631wewqewre8af20c576ad5214ec70f163d600d247bd5d4dfef5453f72ff6::TestContainer::mylobs/blob.del of del LOBS FROM Softlayer::https://lon02.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0::SLOS424907-2:SL523907::0ac631wewqewre8af20c576ad5214ec70f163d600d247bd5d4dfef5453f72ff6::TestContainer::mylobs/ messages on server insert into LOBLOAD')"`